# Wy do we have to concatenate variables in SQL where clause using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I have this code:

`$sql=mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '".$username."'");`

but why so many people do this if

`$query = "SELECT type FROM users WHERE user = '$username' ";`

works fine too? And if we have multiple values we can just do

`$query = "SELECT type FROM users WHERE user = '$username', '$pass' ";`

I couldn't find any explanations on this syntax on the internet.

Comment: Because if magic quotes are disabled the latter does not work.

Comment: You shouldn't use either method. You should use a prepared statement for queries.

Comment: But for other strings, I personally use the concatenation method because I consider the other way to be a bad practice that will lead to unexpected results if I one day decide I prefer my strings to be in single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @rickdenhaan so if I had `$username = $_POST['username']` instead of double quotes ` "username" ` the second method may not work if magic quotes are disabled like @paskl said?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yeah I heard about prepared statement, but I was looking at many old SO answers and that bit of not knowing the difference really bothered me, thus this question.

Comment: Sidestepping the security/context of your samples. -- Variable interpolation works just fine. Newcomers tend to recommend/overuse concatenation, because of dated tutorials or misguided advises ("less readable code = faster").

Comment: No, magic quotes has nothing to do with this and hasn't been a thing [since PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php). This is about variable expansion, which PHP always does if a string is [in double quotes or Heredoc format](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). So, `"$username"` will become `"bob"`, but `'$username'` will be the literal string `'$username'`

Comment: @rickdenhaan  The only question I'm left with then is why do we need dots around `"$username"` ?

Comment: In your query you are in a string with double quotes, but *inside* that you have single quotes. Those single quotes have no meaning to PHP in that context. So `"WHERE username = '$username'"` works fine. But let's say you're outputting XML where the attribute uses double quotes but the *string itself* uses single quotes: `echo '<client username="$username" />'`. This wouldn't work, because the string is defined by single quotes and the inner double quotes have no meaning to PHP. To avoid this confusion, I *always* use the concatenation technique. But that's personal preference.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thanks, your last comment made it all clear for me. You should post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Can't post answers to a closed question, but what I said is pretty much what is also explained in the duplicates @mario found.